# qt file readline always returning -1 on second read

Tags: c++, qt, file, io, readline

so I have a list of words that needs to be checked every time. I tried doing this with the following code:

```
bool woordenKloppen=true;

//doorloop alle woorden in de array
for (int i=0;i<woordenlijst.size();i++)
{
    m_woordenlijst->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    m_woordenlijst->reset();

    char buffer[1024];
    qint64 lineLength = m_woordenlijst->readLine(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    //zoek in de woordenlijst zolang het woord niet gevonden is en de woordenlijst niet gedaan is
    while (lineLength!=-1 && woordKlopt==false)
    {
        QString vergelijkWoord=QString(buffer);

        lineLength = m_woordenlijst->readLine(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        //verwijder de return en newline characters van het woord in de file
        vergelijkWoord.remove(vergelijkWoord.length()-2,2);

        //het woord klopt indien het in de woordenlijst staat
        if (woord==vergelijkWoord)
        {
            woordKlopt=true;
        }
    }
    if (!woordKlopt)
    {
        woordenKloppen=false;
    }

    //sluit de woordenlijst
    m_woordenlijst->close();
}

//return true als alle woorden klopten, anders false
return woordenKloppen;
```

This seems to work, every first time the function is called. The second time the lineLength will be -1 and he will just skip the loop. Am I missing something? thanks in advance

the textfile looks like this, just one word on each line:

```
aalfuiken
aalgeer
aalgeren
aalglad
aalgladde
aalkorf
aalkorven
aalkuip
aalkuipen
aalmoes
aalmoezen
aalmoezenier
aalmoezeniers
aalmoezenierskamer
aalmoezenierskamers
aalpomp
aalpompen
aalput
aalputten
```

Comment: Do you set `woordKlopt` to `false` before going in the while loop? Are you absolutely certain that `readLine` returns `-1`?

Comment: yes woordklopt get initialised at false before the loop and yes I debugged it, and it says -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is line endings. In file you have line ending in windows style "\r\n" and you are reading in binary mode. To fix it correct how file is opened:

```
m_woordenlijst->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
```

---

**Off topic**:
best way to read text file in qt is to use QTextStream.

Comment: opening it this way returns false, any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: this line is copy paste from documentation of QFile. I always use QTextStream and never had such problems, you are converting from `char*` to `QString` manually so you also should use QTextStream. It will be easier to maintain file encoding (important if you are support some languages with accented letters or with non Latin alphabet).

Comment: I keep having the same problem, even with QTextStream. The atEnd() function only returns false when I call the function the first time :S

Answer (score 0):

> If a line could not be read but no error ocurred, this function
>   returns 0. If an error occurs, this function returns the length of
>   what could be read, or -1 if nothing was read.

What does `errorString()` tells you?

Comment: So no error occured. It is your data. Perhaps it is not text. Or it contains only one line.

Comment: no it contains a lot of lines of one word :S like I said, the first function call always works, but at the second it returns -1 :S

Comment: I don't see an error in your code. 'unknown error' in errorString() usually means there is no error. Maybe your 'strings' in your file do not end with '\n'. Hard to say. Try using the atEnd() and canReadLine() methods to get more info.

Comment: atEnd() also returns true after the first read :S and canreadline returns true at first read and then also false :S

Comment: Add QIODevice::Text to your open(). Last idea I have. :-/

Comment: I tried opening it that way, and I had to replace the buffer with readline() and such, but now atEnd() is true from the first read :S

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right way, but not closing the file seemed to solve the problem :S

Comment: This does not make sense. At least not with the code snippet you show us here. Is the code above itself in another loop? I strongly advice against just not closing the file and ignore the problem. Something like that **will** bite you sooner or later.

Comment: yes the above code is in another loop, because multiple words should be checked, the only changing variable is woord :S

Comment: I suppose the problem lies earlier that what you have shown us. Nothing what I read here could explain such a strange behavior.

Comment: Thats is strange. This for loop does not make any sense. You are doing (or try to do) x time exactly the same thing: open a file, reset it to the start, read lines, close the file. open exactly the same file, reset it to the start, read exactly the same lines. This seems to be wrong logic, but I admit, currently I don't see how this causes the problem you see.

Comment: yes I just want to check if the words are in the same list, I suppose you could check all words at once, but I don't think that is the problem